# cannot update user laravel wth try catch

Tags: php, laravel

I'm very confuse . I think I'm doing everything right but I cant update my user data  here is my

**web.php**

```
Route::match(['put', 'patch'], '/is-active','Frontend\UserController@update')->name('user.active');
```

I don't want to use resource because I've to custom my own route.

**HTML**

```
 <form action="{{ route('user.active') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('PUT')}}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
 DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        $user = User::find(Auth::id());
        $user->active = '3'; //waiting approve
        $user->save();
        dd($user->active,$user->save());
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->message());
        DB::rollback();
    }
```

Here is my output in `dd()`

```
3 , true
```

After I try to remove try catch and everything work fine. why can't I use try catch in this query ?

Comment: If your code reaches that `dd` call, what exactly should be going wrong?

Comment: Should the rollback be before the `die()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose, you forgot `DB::commit()`
Use it in the end of `try` block